# How to scrape a dictionary from a span tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Result of this :

```
soup.find('span', {'class':'js-date-picker btn--secondary btn--secondary--no-spacing'})
```

```
<span class="js-date-picker btn--secondary btn--secondary--no-spacing" data-clear="/h/?type=ln&amp;search=ethereum&amp;lang=en&amp;searchheadlines=1" data-date='{"sel":false,"latest":1599889680,"now":1599897600}' data-href="/h/?type=ln&amp;search=ethereum&amp;lang=en&amp;searchheadlines=1&amp;d=" href="javascript://">
<span class="btn--secondary__icon"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
<span class="btn--secondary__label">
<span class="dtctxt"><span class="d">12 Sep</span><span class="t"> 06:48</span></span></span>
</span>
```

Now I want to extract `{"sel":false,"latest":1599889680,"now":1599897600}`  from this text

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import ast

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<span class="js-date-picker btn--secondary btn--secondary--no-spacing" data-clear="/h/?type=ln&amp;search=ethereum&amp;lang=en&amp;searchheadlines=1" data-date='{"sel":false,"latest":1599889680,"now":1599897600}' data-href="/h/?type=ln&amp;search=ethereum&amp;lang=en&amp;searchheadlines=1&amp;d=" href="javascript://"></span>
<span class="btn--secondary__icon"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
<span class="btn--secondary__label">
<span class="dtctxt"><span class="d">12 Sep</span><span class="t"> 06:48</span></span></span>
</span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find("span", {"class": "js-date-picker btn--secondary btn--secondary--no-spacing"})
result = soup.get("data-date")
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{"sel":false,"latest":1599889680,"now":1599897600}
```

If you need, you can convert the result to a `dict` object e.g.:

```
data_date = ast.literal_eval(result.replace("false", "False"))
print(data_date['now'])
```

Output: `1599897600`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I used this and it is also working :
```json.loads(soup.find('span', {'class':'js-date-picker btn--secondary btn--secondary--no-spacing'}).get("data-date"))
```